# What Python dependencies to include in a C++ application?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, deployment

I am having trouble figuring out which dependencies I need to include to get the python interpreter to work on a computer without python installed.

I have a C++ application and I use Install Shield to package and release my program. I am embedding python in this application and have it working in my development environment.

In other words, what do I need to include to make my installer stand alone. I do not want people to have to install python on top of my software to make it work.

The application crashes on the `Py_Initialize()` command.

Comment: You need to use something like https://www.pyinstaller.org/

Comment: I'm looking to include a python script in my C++ application. From what I can see, pyinstaller creates an .exe from only python code. I have my python script integrated with C++ and working in my development environment, but it does not work when I package everything into an installer, then install it on a clean machine (without python). That's why I think it is missing some sort of python dependency.

Comment: On Linux you can use `ldd` to see your executables dependencies. I believe `Dependency Walker` on Windows can do a similar thing.